# How to implement a string case insensitive sorted unique ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, observablecollection

How to implement a string case insensitive sorted unique ObservableCollection?

For data entry the user can create stickies for string values they use a lot.
The list needs to be case insensitive unique and sorted.

Did not find a solution on SO and implemented one.
It might be of value to someone.
And might get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I came up with

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace OCstringUnique2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private OCstringUniqueSorted myCol = new OCstringUniqueSorted();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            myCol.Add("bb");
            myCol.Add("aa");
            myCol.Add("zz");
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public OCstringUniqueSorted MyCol { get { return myCol; } }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = tbNew.Text;
            MyCol.Add(s);
        }
    }
    public class OCstringUniqueSorted : ObservableCollection<string> 
    {
        public new void Add(string item)
        {
            if (item == null) return;
            item = item.Trim();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) return;
            if (this.Contains(item)) return;
            if (this.Contains(item, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return;
            base.Add(item);
        }
        protected override void InsertItem(int index, string item)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach(string s in this)
            {
                if(string.Compare(s,item,true) >= 0)
                {
                    base.InsertItem(i, item);
                    return;
                }
                i++;
            }
            base.InsertItem(i, item);
        }
    }
}

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="tbNew" />
        <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCol}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should sort your `ObservableCollection` at all, that is not what it was designed to do anyway...

In my opinion you should have a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on top of your `ObservableCollection` that your UI would use for binding and that can very easily be sorted by adding [SortDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s...

```
private ICollectionView myCollectionView;
public ICollectionView MyCollectionView...

MyCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, 
    MyListSortDir));
```

This way you don't have to modify your Collection but instead use a layer of abstraction on top of it that you can bind to instead of binding to the actual collection, and with wich you can do whatever you like (including any type of sorting) without affecting the underlying colleciton...

Comment: But this is a collection that I ONLY want to use as unique and sorted.  Why sort every return?  Can CollectionViewSource enforce unique?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Filter event to exclude non-unique items and I don't think it's sorting on every return, only as new items are added...

Comment: OK but I don't want to just exclude non-unique items from presentation. I don't want non-unique times to even go in the list.

Comment: Well, you have to be adding items to your collection somehow... you can exclude non-unique items at that point... right?

Comment: I mean, if you're getting items from the DB you'd use Distinct in your query and only get unique items...

Comment: Did I say I was getting values from the DB?  "For data entry the user can create stickies for string values they use a lot".  Please accept the question on face value.

Comment: That was just an example... why can't you implement unique checking at the point where you add items to your OC from user input?

Comment: So what if I can check on input?  I don't want to.  I want a collection to enfoce that and implement INotifyCollectionChanged.     If I was going to put a unique constraint on a SQL column would you tell me you don't need that - rather I should check on input.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47058/discussion-between-blam-and-dean-k)